# How to display months in full text for Date fields in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

When using Date field in forms with Symfony2, they are displayed in three different select boxes. 
Something like :

```
dd/mm/YYYY
```

What we would like to do is display the months in text `January`, `February`.... instead of 1,2,3...

How to force display in full text for the months dropdown ?

EDIT : Here is the code I use in my form class :

```
$builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array(
    'format' => 'dd - MM - yyyy',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')-70)
));
```

EDIT2 : Image showing F

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the code of the DateType class, it has a format option:

```
$allowedFormatOptionValues = array(
            \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
            \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
            \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
            \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        );

        // If $format is not in the allowed options, it's considered as the pattern of the formatter if it is a string
        if (!in_array($format, $allowedFormatOptionValues, true)) {
            if (is_string($format)) {
                $defaultOptions = $this->getDefaultOptions($options);

                $format = $defaultOptions['format'];
                $pattern = $options['format'];
            } else {
                throw new CreationException('The "format" option must be one of the IntlDateFormatter constants (FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT) or a string representing a custom pattern');
            }
        }

$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
        \Locale::getDefault(),
        $format,
        \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
        \DateTimeZone::UTC,
        \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        $pattern
    );
```

**UPDATE**

```
$builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array(
    'format' => 'dd - MMMM - yyyy',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')-70)
));
```

Comment: Could you give an example using the code I added in the question?

Comment: Thanks, for your quick answer but I already tried that, and the `F` is not being interpreted by Symfony.

Comment: This must be because `date()` is actually not used. This class : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php is used instead

Comment: Great job! Any idea how to translate those messages now?

Comment: I added more sf code. It appears you're supposed to configure your default locale.