# How to use birthday field in symfony2 forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

[Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html) say that we can use birthday date in forms. but they have not given any example how to use that

Can anyone please tell me where do I need to write `birthday` in doctrine entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Birthday is the form_widget.

ex. in controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('yearOfBirth', 'birthday')
        ->getForm();
```

This widget can be mapped to DateTime field

```
/**
 * @var date $yearOfBirth
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="year_of_birth", type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $yearOfBirth;
```

Here you got reference to docs about this field:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 1):

```
$builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday');
```

You have plenties of example on the internet:

- [How to display months in full text for Date fields in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269519/how-to-display-months-in-full-text-for-date-fields-in-symfony2)
- http://j-place.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/creer-premiere-application-web-avec-symfony2/#LX-A