# Symfony2 Birthday form field has blank years

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

The birthday form type is rendering the following HTML. Notice years 1893-1901, which are blank. It looks really bad and I'm not sure why it is blank. According to the docs, this might be expected if using a timestamp, but I am using the default options, so it should be a `DateTime`.

```
<div class=" controls" >
    <select id="study_mainbundle_userprofile_dateOfBirth_month" name="study_mainbundle_userprofile[dateOfBirth][month]" required="required"    class="inline input-mini">
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
        <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
        <option value="7">Jul</option>
        <option value="8">Aug</option>
        <option value="9">Sep</option>
        <option value="10">Oct</option>
        <option value="11">Nov</option>
        <option value="12">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <select id="study_mainbundle_userprofile_dateOfBirth_day" name="study_mainbundle_userprofile[dateOfBirth][day]" required="required"    class="inline input-mini">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select id="study_mainbundle_userprofile_dateOfBirth_year" name="study_mainbundle_userprofile[dateOfBirth][year]" required="required"    class="inline input-small">
        <option value="1893"></option>
        <option value="1894"></option>
        <option value="1895"></option>
        <option value="1896"></option>
        <option value="1897"></option>
        <option value="1898"></option>
        <option value="1899"></option>
        <option value="1900"></option>
        <option value="1901"></option>
        <option value="1902">1902</option>
        <option value="1903">1903</option>
        <option value="1904">1904</option>
        <option value="1905">1905</option>
        <option value="1906">1906</option>
        <option value="1907">1907</option>
        <option value="1908">1908</option>
        <option value="1909">1909</option>
        <option value="1910">1910</option>
        <option value="1911">1911</option>
        <option value="1912">1912</option>
        <option value="1913">1913</option>
        <option value="1914">1914</option>
        <option value="1915">1915</option>
        <option value="1916">1916</option>
        <option value="1917">1917</option>
        <option value="1918">1918</option>
        <option value="1919">1919</option>
        <option value="1920">1920</option>
        <option value="1921">1921</option>
        <option value="1922">1922</option>
        <option value="1923">1923</option>
        <option value="1924">1924</option>
        <option value="1925">1925</option>
        <option value="1926">1926</option>
        <option value="1927">1927</option>
        <option value="1928">1928</option>
        <option value="1929">1929</option>
        <option value="1930">1930</option>
        <option value="1931">1931</option>
        <option value="1932">1932</option>
        <option value="1933">1933</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1936">1936</option>
        <option value="1937">1937</option>
        <option value="1938">1938</option>
        <option value="1939">1939</option>
        <option value="1940">1940</option>
        <option value="1941">1941</option>
        <option value="1942">1942</option>
        <option value="1943">1943</option>
        <option value="1944">1944</option>
        <option value="1945">1945</option>
        <option value="1946">1946</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Entity part:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_of_birth", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $dateOfBirth;
```

form part:

```
        ->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array(
            'label' => 'Date of Birth'
        ))
```

I am using MopaBootstrapBundle if that makes a difference.

Comment: how many 112 year olds are you expecting?

Comment: Have you researched theyr docs? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html and possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947753/how-to-use-birthday-field-in-symfony2-forms

Comment: @Dagon, none, but it looks bad when the form renders with several blanks that you can select. I'd prefer to not display blank options.  I have read the docs. The only other thing I see in the docs is that I could set my own years array. Seems kind of odd, but I'll probably just do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the years manually give the same results : `add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array(
            'label' => 'Date of Birth',
            'years' => range(1893, date('Y')),
            'mapped' => false
        ))`

Years before 1901 are still missing. I don't see if it comes from an Symfony2 or PHP limitation.

Comment: I figured something like `add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array( 'label' => 'Date of Birth', 'years' => range(date('Y')-90, date('Y'))))` would be a good enough work around. But if you repro this bug too, I'll take a look at the github issues and report it.

Comment: I found the issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5227 I have 64-bit Windows with XAMPP. I believe that this means I'm running 32-bit PHP, thought I'm not home now to check (why do they do that? Who still uses a 32-bit system?).